# dynamic changed id of aspx textBox

Tags: asp.net

```
txtRestaurantSearch.ID = "txtSearch";    
TextBox textbox = (TextBox)Page.FindControl("txtSearch");
```

which is always null. How can i get value from dynamic changed id of aspx textBox

whole code:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/HeaderFooter.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" 
    CodeBehind="Search.master.cs" Inherits="FoodOrder.MasterPages.Search" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="cplMPHead" runat="server">    
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cplMPHead" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>  
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="cplMPBody" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManagerProxy ID="ScriptManagerProxy1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManagerProxy>
    <div class="search">
        <ul class="tabs">
            <li ID="liRestaurnat" runat="server">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="hlRestaurant" 
                    runat="server" CssClass="active" Text="Poišči restavracijo" 
                    ToolTip="Poišči po imenu restavracije" NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" 
                    onclick="hlRestaurant_Click" ></asp:LinkButton>
            </li>
            <li ID="liAddress" runat="server" class="second">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="hlAddress" 
                    runat="server" Text="Iskanje po krajih" ToolTip="Poišči po imenu kraja" 
                    NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" onclick="hlAddress_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="search_place">  
            <ul>    
                <li>
                    <fieldset>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtRestaurantSearch" CssClass="input_big" runat="server" Text="" 
                            enableviewstate="true" ontextchanged="txtSearch_TextChanged" />
                    </fieldset>
                </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

your code should work (it is working on my machine). Have you set viewstate to true ?

```
txtRestaurantSearch.ID = "txtSearch";
TextBox textbox = (TextBox)Page.FindControl("txtSearch");
textbox.Text = textbox.ID;
```

OUTPUT should be

> txtSearch

Comment: yes. <asp:TextBox ID="txtRestaurantSearch" CssClass="input_big" runat="server" Text="" 
                            enableviewstate="true" ontextchanged="txtSearch_TextChanged" />

Comment: where you have placed your textbox in page ? I mean to say in container, gridview, html table etc.

Comment: in html inside <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="cplMPBody" runat="server">

Comment: **you should read [this link](http://www.asp.net/master-pages/tutorials/control-id-naming-in-content-pages-cs)**

Answer (score 0):

Following is C# code.

```
// Get a reference to the master page 
MasterPage mp =(MasterPage) FindControl("ctl00");
// Get a reference to the ContentPlaceHolder 
ContentPlaceHolder MainContent = (ContentPlaceHolder) mp.FindControl("cplMPBody");
// Reference the TextBox controls 
TextBox textbox = (TextBox)MainContent.FindControl("txtRestaurantSearch");
textbox.ID = "txtSearch";
string str=textbox.Text;
```

Comment: MasterPage masterPage = (MasterPage)FindControl("HeaderFooter");
                    ContentPlaceHolder contentPlaceHolder = (ContentPlaceHolder)masterPage.FindControl("cplMPBody"); but one masterpage is inside another. What i am still doing wrong that this not working. thx

Comment: thx. Thi is ok now. But i still can not get data from textbox. i chnage id of Textbox to txtRestaurantSearch.ID = "txtSearch"; so ID in source code is now ctl00_ctl00_cplMPBody_txtAddressSearch

Comment: more detail is needed to uderstand your problem.

Comment: textbox.text is "", it does not have any value. i write "Text" in textbox but it is empty. I suppose becouse i change his ID to txtRestaurantSearch.ID = "txtSearch";

Comment: When we executes `TextBox textbox = (TextBox)MainContent.FindControl("txtRestaurantSearch"); ` then `textbox` has the reference of your TextBox control. Changing ID does not matters. You can access `Text` property of `textbox` without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a working example.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MasterPage mp = (MasterPage)FindControl("ctl00");
    ContentPlaceHolder cp = (ContentPlaceHolder)mp.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");
    TextBox tb = (TextBox)cp.FindControl("TextBox1");
    tb.ID = "txtSearch";
    tb.Text = tb.ID+tb.Text;
}
```

after putting some value in textbox you can access its `Text`property.